# Is calf compression as useful as foot compression on a plane?

Tags: air-travel, health

I have both compression socks that go to my ankles and [compression sleeves](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PZ5HTGS). I purchased the sleeves to treat shin splints.

I have heard compression is useful on planes to help with blood flow. Is there an advantage to wearing the sleeves as well as the socks? I have an upcoming eight-hour flight.